# Can Progressive Web Apps set up GPS in their web apps

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I want to make PWA in which its primary feature is GPS i.e. location based services but some of the sites are saying that a PWA does not support GPS, camera and many other features and some of the sites says that it does support GPS. I am confused.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PWA do not support GPS *in the background*. W3C/IETF/WHATWG have been aware of the demand and deed for this feature for at least 5 years and have ignored a [perfectly good solution](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/TravelManagerPolyfill.js) for over 3 years :-(

There is discusstions going on in [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193946) about supporting this now.

If you use Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic then you can run GPS in the background as a hybrid app.

Comment: As you said that PWA does not support GPS in the background that means we will not be able to track the location of the user?

Comment: Only if your App is in the foreground. I believe there are varying results when the phone goes to sleep depending on the browser. You could wait got navigator.getWakeLock("screen") but that will be highly inefficient on battery life. *Please* add your +1 to the WebKit bug I referenced,